# How to open local files from firefox extensions in browser?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

**I am trying to show downloaded files in the browser and it's working in chrome from chrome extension.**
**I want to open up to folder as in ss.**

Working result in chrome looks like this:
[image]

Code used to open local file in chrome is:

```
chrome.tabs.create({
        url: localFileUrl,
        index: baseTab.index + 1,
});
```

**eg: localFileUrl= "file:///C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\test"**

**From the Firefox extension I have used following code to open local
files in the new tab:**

```
    browser.tabs.create({
        url: localFileUrl,
        index: baseTab.index + 1,
    }).then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
});
```

and in the console I get the error like this..
[image]

**How can I open local files in Firefox from extension same like in chrome from chrome extension?!**

I have added permissions *tabs* and *activeTab* in manifest.json file.

Comment: Firefox probably doesn't implement this.

Comment: Is there any work around to open local files from extensions?

Comment: There is no workaround since Firefox intentionally blocked local filesystem access to extension for security reasons. However, extensions can process a tab with 'file:///...` URL, if user opens such URL.

Comment: How extension can process a tab with  'file:///...` URL ? can you elaborate more ? @erosman

Comment: Once user opens a tab with `file:///...` URL, then AFA extension, it is just a normal tab. Extension can process it. Extension can add listeners to wait for such tab to be opened. It depends on what the extension intends to do.